# Setting apache server wide variables with python

Tags: python, apache, variables, kml

I would like to be able to call a python script that checks to see if the variables passed to it have already been passed to it and if not then spit out a KML file for google earth to read. I've looked at environment variables to no avail. But essentially I need to store a string so that the next time the script is called I can reference it. I'll post what I have below. Thanks and any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I suppose I didn't clearly state the issue, I'm attempting to call a python script on an Apache server with KML passing URL variables to the script. One of the URL variables contains a time string, I would like to store that time and be able to reference it to the next "Time" that is passed to the script, IF the times don't match then print out certain KML, If they DO match then print empty script so that Google Earth doesn't duplicate a placemark. In essence I am filtering the KML files so that I can avoid duplicates. I've also updated the code below.

---

```
import cgi
import os

url = cgi.FieldStorage()
bbox = url['test'].value
bbox = bbox.split(',')
lat = float(bbox[0])
lon = float(bbox[1])
alt = float(bbox[2])
when = str(bbox[3])

if when == os.environ['TEMP']:
    kml = ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
           '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">\n'
           '</kml>')
else:
    kml = ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
           '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">\n'
           '<NetworkLinkControl>\n'
           '<Update>\n'
           '<targetHref>http://localhost/GE/Placemark.kml</targetHref>\n'
           '<Create>\n'
           '<Folder targetId="fld1">\n'
           '<Placemark>\n'
           '<name>View-centered placemark</name>\n'
           '<TimeStamp>\n'
           '<when>%s</when>\n'
           '</TimeStamp>\n'
           '<Point>\n'
           '<coordinates>%.6f,%.6f,%.6f</coordinates>\n'
           '</Point>\n'
           '</Placemark>\n'
           '</Folder>\n'
           '</Create>\n'
           '</Update>\n'
           '</NetworkLinkControl>\n'
           '</kml>'
           ) % (when, lat, lon, alt)

os.environ['TEMP'] = when
print('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml\n')
print(kml)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a few options here to share a state:

- Use a db.
- file system based persistence
- a separate daemon process that you can connect to via sockets
- Use memcache or some other service to store in memory
- You can share states via python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)
- You can also create a [manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and have proxy [objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects):

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out. By a separate daemon process what do you mean? Like a process that sits and waits for information and will stay running?

Comment: I also like the idea of a db I have some experience with mySQL db's and just wondered your opinion on how efficient that would be. However, I suppose that also is a dependent of the server speed.

Comment: DataBase was for sure the way to go. Thanks.